# Button not clickable - Disable Click

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to make a button in ionic **not clickable**, so how can I do it?

I have buttons inside a header bar and they are scores, so people can't click on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ng-disable`

```
<button ng-disable="true"></button>
```

Comment: How do I do it dynamically?

Comment: how can i do it from typescript?